# What are possible types to choose in the Invocable.Action.createCustomAction(type, name) method?

Tags: apex, invocable-method, release-notes

In the Winter '23 Release there was a new Apex class added - [Invocable.Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Invocable_Action.htm)

One can invoke an action using, for instance, a `createCustomAction(type, name)` method. However, there are no possible types listed in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Invocable_Action.htm#apex_Invocable_Action_createCustomAction_2).

`apex` is the only one that I got, as it's used in examples.

I didn't find anything useful neither in the [Release Maintenance Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform-developer-i-certification-maintenance-winter-23/maintain-your-platform-developer-i-certification-for-winter-23?trail_id=maintain-your-salesforce-certifications) nor in the [Help Docs for the Release](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_invocableaction_class.htm&release=240&type=5).

Is there anywhere a list of possible types to use here available?

Comment: Looks like you can put anything: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.invocable_actions.htm&type=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the supported types (from /services/data/v58.0/actions/custom)

- `apex` for calling @InvocableAction annotated methods
- `flow` for starting Flow interviews (including mass/bulk runs)
- `quickAction` for calling Global Publisher actions

I found them via Workbench REST Explorer and tested each in Apex. The unsupported ones throw an error, eg: `Invocable.Action.createCustomAction('emailAlert', '').invoke()`

- `externalService` for making HTTP callouts
- `dynamicSendSurveyInvitation` for Salesforce Survey links
- `sendNotification` for Send Notification relate to Slack integrations
- `outboundMessage` which refers to object-specific Workflow Rules and SOAP
- `emailAlert` which also refers to object-specific Workflow Rules and emails

[image: workbench-custom-actions]